# how to access event target elements outside the onclick funtion

Tags: javascript

I have a product page with a button which has the `onclick` and function called `passprops`. the event target inside that function gets all the clicked product elements. I confirmed everything with console.log and it prints all the correct information. My issue is that I'm unable to get those values from outside the `onclick` fn. 
This is for practice so the code is simple:

HTML product code :

```html
<div>
    <span id="product">test addbutton component</span>
    <span id="price">00</span>
    <span id="description"> component test</span>
    <span id="id" hidden="">1000</span>
    <p class="center">
        <Addbutton on:click={passprops} />
    </p>
</div>
```

My js script:

```html
<script>
    //assign all the e event target element to these variables
    let titlep
    let pricep
    let descriptionp
    let idp

    function passprops(e) {
        let items = e.target.parentElement.parentElement
        let title = items.firstChild.innerHTML
        console.log("title:", title)
        titlep = title // is this is the right way to assign the value  of title to titlep?
        let price = items.children[1].innerHTML
        pricep = price
        let description = items.children[2].innerHTML
        let id = items.children[3].innerHTML
        titleppp()

    }
</script>
```

but the title, price, description and id are undefined when I click the button.
What am I doing wrong?
I'm missing something here. 
How do I get the value of the product clicked to be assigned to those variables in the scope outside the function?

Comment: Where, when and how are you accessing these variables? Notice, that `firstChild` could be a textnode, it's safest to use `firstElementChild`. That doesn't explain `.children[...]` being undefined, though.

Comment: Are we allowed to rewrite the function to get the same functionality that you're looking for?

Comment: ID always needs to be unique, so you can access all the elements by getElementById eaisly

Comment: @martin yes, you're allowed the rewrite the same function. This is just a practice example so feel free to modify anyway you like as long as you show me how to assign the innerHTML value to the variables outside the function.

Comment: @AtulRajput Totally agree. I just trying something and did it quicky. It's a practice code not real app. I need to get the values of the clicked product title, price, description and id, assign them to variables outside the function so I use those variables in svelte/sapper app.

Comment: @Teemu This is a practice code. Don't concern yourself with where, when do I use those variables. Those variables will be used in a svelte/sapper app (to answer your question)....do you know how to get the value of the event target innerHTML value and assign it to the variables outside the fn? If yes, please share your code

Comment: We can't reproduce the issue with the provided code, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: As you can see, the code [works as it is](https://jsfiddle.net/y0r5bg2o/1/). (Except the `firstChild` issue I've mention above.)

Comment: @Teemu : Thanks. as long as the code works as is, then I will keep try to figure out why it is showing print undefined in the console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use closest to select the parent,
then you can select its child like this

```
  <p id="ptitle"></p>
  <p id="pprice"></p>
```

```
function passprops(e) {
   let item = e.target.closest('div');
   let title = item.querySelector('#product').inerHTML;
   let price = item.querySelector('#price').inerHTML;

   document.getElementById('ptitle').innerHTML = title;
   document.getElementById('pprice').innerHTML = price; 
}
```

Comment: titlep is not a dom element, it is a js variable used in sapper/sevlte app. I need to get the title, description, price and id and assign them to the variable titlep, pricep, descriptionp and idp to use them in different parts of the app. How do you get the event target innerHTML and assign that value to the variable outside the fn scope?

Comment: to get the event target inerhtml use my code above, first you select the parent (item) then from item you can chain the selector by id item.queryselector, to assign the var outside the scope then you need a global variable like this let a = 10;

 const x = _ => {
  a = 11;
 }
 x();

Comment: : Is the global variable code goes inside the fn passprops? I did that but it didn't work. The variable still undefined. Could you update your code so I follow the example, if you have time of course? Thank you

Comment: never mind. I figured out what you meant. So basically, I can't assign the global variable to the local scope value from the event target fn. I have to do round trip, first get the event target value, assign it to a hidden element and then use a queryselector to get that value and assign it to global variable.

Comment: Thank you Ricky Orlando. You were very helpful with your answer. I appreciate it.

Comment: sorry for late response, yes you can change outside variable from a fn just like this code let a = 10; const x = _ => { a = 11; } x();  i define var a = 10 then i execute function x() which defining a to be 11, then when i console the value it should be 11

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I am typing this as the question already has an accepted answer, however, I'd like to add a ***jQuery*** version as well with some tweaks to what OP's original thought process was.

OP had all the selectors available to them, since they have assigned `id`'s to their element tags that they wish to fetch. Yet they went for an unspecified approach as if they did not have those selectors available to them (by going through parent and child selections etc.).

So my answer will focus on that approach, as if they did not have specified selectors to go by, but rather knew the display order of the product information, i.e.

1. Title
2. Price
3. Description

One way to do this is by making an array with the values in question and then assign those values to their appropriate variables.

First we'd go by the approach that OP took, by finding the container parent. This will simplify the code later on for readability.

Example:

```
let container = $(this).parents('div').last();
```

We now assigned the variable `container` to be the surrounding div element of the product structure in the HTML.

Like I mentioned earlier, in this approach, we assume that we do not know the selectors of the elements we're trying to find, but only know their tag, i.e. `<span>`. So what we can do here, is that we can declare an array, loop through the `<span>` elements and `push()` the array values with the `<span>` elements `.html()` values in order to populate the array.

Declaring the array:

```
let items = [];
```

A way to loop through the `<span>` elements would be to find the `<span>` elements within the `container` variable that was created earlier and use the `.each()` function and then `push()` the values into the array.

Example:

```
container.find('span').each(function() {
    items.push( $(this).html() );
});
```

Note that arrays always start from an index position of `0`. Since we know the order of our variables, we can now assign the variables to our array values.

Example:

```
titlep = items[0];
pricep = items[1];
idp = items[2];
```

***Full, runable codensippet Example:***

```js
let titlep;
let pricep;
let descriptionp;
let idp;

$("#addButton").on( "click", function() {
 let container = $(this).parents('div').last();
 let items = [];
 
 container.find('span').each(function() {
  items.push( $(this).html() );
 });
 
 titlep = items[0];
 pricep = items[1];
 idp = items[2];
 
 console.log('titlep = '+titlep);
 console.log('pricep = '+pricep);
 console.log('idp = '+idp);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span>test addbutton component</span><br />
    <span>00</span><br />
    <span> component test</span><br />
    <span hidden="">1000</span>
    <p class="center">
       <button id="addButton">Add Button</button>
    </p>
</div>
```

Please note that I do recommend the simpler solution when you do have the selectors available. I.e. the answer by @Ricky Orlando Napitupulu.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Very well put together answer.